# Finding the definition of Pineburr

Tags: meaning

This morning we crossed a street named Pineburr.  Note, there is no space; it is one word.  We've looked for that word on the web and in dictionaries without any luck.  Anyone know its meaning, derivation and usage?

Wes

Comment: It's probably a variant of pinecone.

Comment: That is my guess also.  Just checking for further insight.

Comment: The compounding of nouns often proceeds spasmodically; this is probably someone's attempt at 'pine burr'. A Google image search for the open compound gives a lot of pretty quilt patterns, but no explanation.

Comment: Whether there's a space or not is completely irrelevant in place names. They usually go back to when orthography was much less fixed than nowadays, so they can be spelt in all manner of bizarre ways, including joining or separating words in odd places.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Google Books search finds numerous examples of *pine burr* (or *pine bur*) from U.S. publications starting in the 18th century. The earliest is from Thomas Jefferson, "[Memoranda taken on a journey from Paris into the southern parts of France, and northern of Italy, in the year 1787](https://books.google.com/books?id=iNMcAQAAIAAJ&pg=PA333&dq=%22pine+bur%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=NVKKVMTEKM23oQTxnILgBQ&ved=0CEEQ6AEwBTgU#v=onepage&q=%22pine%20bur%22&f=false)," reprinted in *The Writings of Thomas Jefferson*, volume 9 (1854):

> *Nice.* [April 9, 1878.] The **pine bur** is used here for kindling fires. The people are in separate establishments. With respect to the orange, there seems to be no climate on this side of the Alps, sufficiently mild in itself to preserve it without shelter.

From "[Report of Theodore Bland, on the Condition of Soth America](https://books.google.com/books?id=8GwzAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA297&dq=%22pine+burr%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=QEqKVOWKOYvboATQ24KwBQ&ved=0CFIQ6AEwCDgK#v=onepage&q=%22pine%20burr%22&f=false) " (November 2, 1818) in U.S. Congress, *American State Papers: Documents, Legislative and Executive, of the Congress of the United States*, volume 4 (1834):

> That species of bullion called *plata pina*, from the silver having been cast into lumps resembling a **pine burr**, is worth one-eighth more than the standard coin. This furnishes another inducement to smuggle; and, so soon as it shall be well ascertained that plata pina may be passed for the same superior value in China which it bears in Chili, this inducement will be much increased.

From Henry Schoolcraft, [*Algic Researches: Comprising Inquiries Respecting the Mental Characteristics of the North American Indians, Indian Tales and Legends*](https://books.google.com/books?id=chUHAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA58&dq=%22gnawing+the+top+of+a+pine+bur%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=bVGKVIq1BNXdoASKxYDoDw&ved=0CEYQ6AEwBw#v=onepage&q=%22gnawing%20the%20top%20of%20a%20pine%20bur%22&f=false) (1839):

> One day after a fruitless trial of his forest skill the little boy was returning homeward with a heavy heart, when he saw a small red squirrel gnawing the top of a **pine bur**. He had approached within a proper distance to shoot, when the squirrel sat up on its hind legs and thus addressed him:
>
> “My grandchild, put up your arrows, and listen to what I have to tell you.”

From Samuel Goodrich, "[Birmah](https://books.google.com/books?id=vdRAAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA90&dq=%22pine+burr%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=CFmKVNz9K4TuoAT_4YCYAg&ved=0CE4Q6AEwCA#v=onepage&q=%22pine%20burr%22&f=false)," in *Supplement to the Pictorial Geography of the World, for 1841 and 1842* (1842):

> To comb the warp [of a Burmese loom], they use the fruit of the sahtha, a strong grass, eight or ten feet high, with jagged, thorny leaves. The fruit is the size of an ostrich egg, having a shell like a young **pine burr**. This being removed, leaves a sharp, strong hair, which makes an excellent brush for the purpose.

From William Simms, "[Logoochie](https://books.google.com/books?id=VuISAAAAIAAJ&pg=PA92&dq=%22green+in+season.+It+rose+into+a%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=u1SKVMW0GYXuoAT7_oLoCw&ved=0CD8Q6AEwBA#v=onepage&q=%22green%20in%20season.%20It%20rose%20into%20a%22&f=false)," in *Carl Werner, an Imaginative Story, with Other Tales of the Imagination*, volume 2 (1838):

> The back of Logoochie [the Trickster spirit in Creek Indian mythology] was, itself, little better than a stripe of the tree bark to those who remarked it casually. From his heel to his head, inclusive, it looked like so many articulated folds or scales of the pine tree, here and there bulging out in excrescences. The back of his head was a solid knot, hard and resinous. This knot ran across in front, so as to arch above and overhang his forehead, and was crowned with hair that, though soft, was thick and woody to the eye, and looked not unlike the plates of the **pine-bur** when green in season. It rose into a ridge or comb directly across the head from front to rear, like the war tuft of a Seminole warrior.

And from "[Report of Hon. T. Butler King on California](https://books.google.com/books?id=l3AUAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA16&dq=%22pine+burr%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=W1eKVNT9CsfhoATW2YHwDA&ved=0CFUQ6AEwCDgK#v=onepage&q=%22pine%20burr%22&f=false)" (1850):

> The small bands [of mountain Indians] with whom I met ... live chiefly on acorns, roots, and insects, and the kernel of the **pine burr**: occasionally they catch fish and game. They use the bow and arrow, but are said to be too lazy and effeminate to make successful hunters.

From these various instances of the term in context, it seems clear to me that *pine burr* (or *pine bur*) is synonymous with *pinecone*.

Answer (score 0):

Burr:

3. a rough or irregular protuberance, such as a burl on a tree

http://www.thefreedictionary.com/burr

It could be a reference to something like this:

http://www.idahohotsprings.com/destinations/pine_burl/061607/pine-burl-hot-springs-03.jpg

I am not sure, though. If you are very curious, consider seeking out a local historian, or the Department of Transportation for that area (or whatever authority would have named the path).

Comment: Well, it's on te campus at Cisco in Research Triangle Park, NC.  Now all I have to do is find out who built the place.....

Comment: If it's actually *on* Cisco campus, those are not public roads, and were probably named by Cisco.